# Javascript - How to concatenate string values from two arrays of different sizes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, for example:

Array1:

```
arr1 = ["Precon", "Contra", "Postco", "Cancel", "Consul"]
```

Array2:

```
arr2 = ["EJID", "EMBA", "EMPR", "GOBI", "PART", "PPOL", "SACI", "SOFL", "SOFM", "0000", "", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", "0009", "0010", "0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015", "0016", "011", "0110", "9999"]
```

I want to generate a new array from two above concatenating the individual items into new items recursively for each one in array1, to get a final array like this:

```
final = ['Precon-EJID', 'Contra-EJID', 'Postco-EJID', 'Cancel-EJID', 'Consul-EJID', 'Precon-EMBA', 'Contra-EMBA', 'Postco-EMBA', 'Cancel-EMBA', 'Consul-EMBA', 'Precon-EMPR', 'Contra-EMPR', 'Postco-EMPR', 'Cancel-EMPR', 'Consul-EMPR'...etc]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What issue are you having with the code that you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: What have you tried? This can be done with a number of different loop approaches

Comment: is the order in `final` important

Comment: The multiple answers posted to this Question prove that the "downvote" and "close" vote standards and rationales, if any, are fully arbitrary and capricious. Which is ok. Just be aware that it is duly noted if any of the users whom answered this Question find the audacity to post a comment questioning this users' answering any question here at SO whatsoever. None of the users whom posted answers to this question should vote to close another question under the premise of "off-topic because -> ("why isn't this code working?")" else that vote is fraudulent even if only you know that fact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with 2 simple `for of` loops:

```js
var arr1 = ["Precon", "Contra", "Postco", "Cancel", "Consul"];

var arr2 = ["EJID", "EMBA", "EMPR", "GOBI", "PART", "PPOL", "SACI", "SOFL", "SOFM", "0000", "", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", "0009", "0010", "0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015", "0016", "011", "0110", "9999"]

var finalArr = [];

for ( var item2 of arr2 ) {
  for ( var item1 of arr1 ) {
    finalArr.push(`${item1}-${item2}`);
  }
}

console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls, and flatten the results using [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const arr1 = ["Precon", "Contra", "Postco", "Cancel", "Consul"]

const arr2 = ["EJID", "EMBA", "EMPR", "GOBI", "PART", "PPOL", "SACI", "SOFL", "SOFM", "0000", "", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", "0009", "0010", "0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015", "0016", "011", "0110", "9999"]

const result = [].concat(...arr2.map((s1) => arr1.map((s2) => `${s2}-${s1}`)))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Solid answer. It's a little messy having to use the new spread syntax (`...`), but works and doesn't require a third "building array".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner to do this:

```js
arr1 = ["Precon", "Contra", "Postco", "Cancel", "Consul"]
arr2 = ["EJID", "EMBA", "EMPR", "GOBI", "PART", "PPOL", "SACI", "SOFL", "SOFM", "0000", "", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", "0009", "0010", "0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015", "0016", "011", "0110", "9999"]

const result = [].concat(...arr1.map(prefix => arr2.map(suffix => prefix+suffix)));
console.log(result)

// EDIT: if order matters, reverse the use of arr1 and arr2:

const orderedResult = [].concat(...arr2.map(suffix => arr1.map(prefix => prefix+suffix)));
console.log(orderedResult)
```

Comment: why `[].concat`?

Comment: your output does not match desired output :p

Comment: Flattens the array so that all items are at the same level. Without it, the result would be a 2-dimensional array: `[["PreconEJID", ...], ["ContraEJID", ...], ...]`

Comment: @JaromandaX I though it did? In what way? OP's final array is not nested. Or do you mean the order is incorrect?

Comment: @CRice OP does not specify any particular ordering of the result

Comment: yep, `const result = [].concat(...arr2.map(suffix => arr1.map(prefix => prefix+suffix)));`

Comment: @guest271314 - *to get a final array like this* ... see the **order** in the partial output? it's obvious the OP wants tht order

Comment: Agree with @guest271314, I didn't think the order matters. But as @JaromandaX points out, reversing the use of `arr1` and `arr2` will solve that issue. EDIT: I've edited the answer to include the fixed ordering, just in case.

Comment: @JaromandaX That is a plausible interpretation of the Question.

Comment: The output order matters, I forget to mention that in the question, so this approach gets the correct result but in first array order.

Comment: This is pretty much @OriDrori's answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
const prefixes = [
  "Precon",
  "Contra",
  "Postco",
  "Cancel",
  "Consul"
];

const suffixes = [
  "EJID", "EMBA", "EMPR",
  "GOBI", "PART", "PPOL",
  "SACI", "SOFL", "SOFM",
  "0000", "", "0002",
  "0003", "0004", "0005",
  "0006", "0007", "0008",
  "0009", "0010", "0011",
  "0012", "0013", "0014",
  "0015", "0016", "011",
  "0110", "9999"
];

const results = suffixes
  .map(suffix => prefixes.map(prefix => prefix + '-' + suffix))
  .reduce((xs, ys) => [...xs, ...ys]);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: There should be dashes between the prefix/suffixes

Comment: @FrankerZ If we are positing what "should be". There should first be a modicum of effort put forth by OP to resolve their own inquiry, which is wholly absent from the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use reduce...

```js
let arr1 = ["Precon", "Contra", "Postco", "Cancel", "Consul"]

let arr2 = ["EJID", "EMBA", "EMPR", "GOBI", "PART", "PPOL", "SACI", "SOFL", "SOFM", "0000", "", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", "0009", "0010", "0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015", "0016", "011", "0110", "9999"]

let arr3 = arr2.reduce((arr, val) => {
    let f = []
    arr1.forEach(itm => val && f.push(itm + '-' + val))
    return arr.concat(f)
}, [])

console.log(arr3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive one. Just like the OP asked. Took me a while. :P

```js
arr1 = ["Precon", "Contra", "Postco", "Cancel", "Consul"]

arr2 = ["EJID", "EMBA", "EMPR", "GOBI", "PART", "PPOL", "SACI", "SOFL", "SOFM", "0000", "", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005", "0006", "0007", "0008", "0009", "0010", "0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015", "0016", "011", "0110", "9999"]

var arr = [];

console.log(concat(arr1, arr2, 0, 0, 0));

function concat(arr1, arr2, arrIndex, index1, index2) {
  //console.log(arr1.length);
  if (index2 === (arr2.length)) {
    return;
  } else {
    arr[arrIndex] = arr1[index1] + '-' + arr2[index2];
    if (index1 !== (arr1.length - 1)) {
      index1++;
    } else if (index1 === (arr1.length - 1)) {
      index1 = 0;
      index2++;
      //concat(arr1, arr2, ++arrIndex, index1, index2++); // Not here dummy :P
    }
    concat(arr1, arr2, ++arrIndex, index1, index2++);
  }
  return arr;
}
```